# Closing the lid of my notebook doesn't have any effect

Tags: laptop, power, power-management, lid

When I close the lid on my Samsung 900x3c-A01 nothing happens, both on Windows and Linux... I've made double-sure all the OS' settings are correct, I even tried to set them up so they would shut down on lid close, but still nothing. How can I make sure that it is a hardware issue before sending my laptop to a service point?

Comment: If you've tried multiple OS's, that's about all you can try.  Short of locating the switch and manually triggering it to test (which often isn't possible without opening the notebook), it's time to take it in.

Comment: Don't know if it's related to lid opening, but did you install latest drivers for HECI from samsung site?

Comment: I can't seem to find HECI drivers on the manufacturer's site. Can they be called something different?

Comment: Now anytime I close the lid the laptop keeps on pressing ctrl+shift+n... What might be the cause of that?